# Correct code placement for Google Remarketing

Tags: google-ads-api

I am just wondering why it is in [Google Remarketing](https://www.wordstream.com/google-remarketing), that we need to put the code at the bottom of the page before the `</body>` tag?

Maybe they need to load the page completely to save it in cookies or something?

I tried to see here:
[Tag your site for remarketing](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2476688?ref_topic=2677439&hl=en)

Comment: Where did you see it has to be at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Re-marketing means when the Visitors view your website then you will show your marketing campaign to that visitors Only. That's the reason Google suggested to put your code Just before the  code. So that google easily understand all the Website Visitors of different-different pages and then Google will show your paid campaign accordingly.

If you are using your code within the header or footer and it is common for all the pages then Google will not understand properly that How many visitors your website have and hence your re-marketing code will not work properly.

**Here is the code of Re-marketing.**

```js
    <script type="text/javascript"> /* <![CDATA[ */ var google_conversion_id = 980814490; var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params; var google_remarketing_only = true; /* ]]> */< /script>< script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">< /script>< noscript>< div style="display:inline;">< img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/980814490/?value=0&guid=O N&script=0"/>< /div>< /noscript>
```

Comment: you can also take a look in this link to embedded your remarketing tag. https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2476688?ref_topic=2677439&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You should add it just after the opening of `<body>`

If you add it next to the closing of `</body>`, the visitor might leave before the remarketing loads. And about `<head>`, Google Tag Manager warns when you add it anywhere in the `<head></head>`.